# Convert Logical Data model into XML Schema

Tags: database-design

Is there any free tool that can convert a Logical Data Model into an XML schema ? IBM suites are paid sws, so I am lookinf for a free option to be able to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Saub

Comment: WHat do you mean by a 'logical data model'?

Answer (score 1):

If you use ERwin for your logical/physical modeling, you may want to check out the last response here:  https://communities.ca.com/web/ca-modeling-global-user-community/message-board/-/message_boards/view_message/2273138

See if this helps.